Excel Formula working but I dont know why
I'm having a bit of trouble on this excel sheet. When I use evaluate, it goes to     1.14     and in the input data sheet there is data but when I evaluate it returns     N/a    . The maddening part is it works for     2.14,3.14,4.14    , etc. but just not 1.14 and the other sister value of     1.16     beside it`
=IF(HLOOKUP($C$21+$CC$8,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,$BZ10,FALSE)<>0,HLOOKUP($C$21+$CC$8,Input_Data!$A$2:$BIN$2502,$BZ10,FALSE), #N/A)
Lookup Data that is there:



Also, when I change the falses to true it works, but it breaks for every other case I try so I can't do that

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but looking at the data sample you posted combined with the formula, I think you need VLOOKUP instead of HLOOKUP.  If possible you can even use XLOOKUP.

Ok when I manually replaced the calculation part that gets 1.14 with just me typing 1.14 it worked why tf does that work

Have you tried doing the lookup part outside of the formula and then evaluate it?

@KoreaSauce my guess is that the value isn't an exact match. It may appear that way from formatting, but 1.141 is not equal to 1.14. I can only see your picture but if it's in the table and isn't finding a match, it'd be because it's not an exact match. Typing it in gives you want you expect, whereas the calculation may have some difference you can adjust with clever rounding functions. Evaluate the math and check if the result is equal to what you expect it to be.
